# fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory, Imgui

Tags: c++, cmake

I am currently trying to build my C++ project with CMake, I am creating an application with graphical interface and use Glad, GLFW and imgui. The problem is that upon running the CMake generated Makefile, I get the following error:

```
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/imgui/imgui.cpp.obj
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/imgui/imgui_demo.cpp.obj
[ 41%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp.obj
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp.obj
C:\Users\Alex_X1\Documents\Programmieren\C++\Project\imgui\imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:76:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
   76 | #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

My CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(Project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

# GLFW
set(GLFW_LIB_DIR "lib")
set(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/GLFW")
set(GLFW_LIB_NAME "libglfw3")
add_library(${GLFW_LIB_NAME} STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(${GLFW_LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${GLFW_LIB_DIR}/libglfw3.a
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR}
)
# GLAD
set(GLAD_DIR "glad")
add_library("glad" "${GLAD_DIR}/glad.c")
target_include_directories(glad PRIVATE "${GLAD_DIR}")
# Imgui
set(IMGUI_DIR "imgui")
file(GLOB IMGUI_SOURCES ${IMGUI_DIR}/*.cpp)
add_library("imgui" ${IMGUI_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(imgui PRIVATE "${IMGUI_DIR}" "${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR}")

add_executable(Project main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLFW_LIB_NAME} glad imgui)
```

My Folder Structure:

```
├───.vscode
├───bin
│   ├───CMakeFiles
│   │   ├───3.26.3
│   │   │   ├───CompilerIdC
│   │   │   │   └───tmp
│   │   │   └───CompilerIdCXX
│   │   │       └───tmp
│   │   ├───pkgRedirects
│   │   ├───Progress
│   │   └───Project.dir
│   └───imgui
│       └───backends
├───build
│   ├───.cmake
│   │   └───api
│   │       └───v1
│   │           ├───query
│   │           │   └───client-vscode
│   │           └───reply
│   └───CMakeFiles
│       ├───3.26.3
│       │   ├───CompilerIdC
│       │   │   └───tmp
│       │   └───CompilerIdCXX
│       │       └───tmp
│       ├───glad.dir
│       │   └───glad
│       ├───imgui.dir
│       │   └───imgui
│       ├───pkgRedirects
│       ├───Progress
│       └───Project.dir
├───glad
├───GLFW
├───imgui
│   ├───.github
│   │   └───workflows
│   ├───backends
│   │   └───vulkan
│   ├───docs
│   ├───examples
│   │   ├───example_allegro5
│   │   ├───example_android_opengl3
│   │   │   └───android
│   │   │       └───app
│   │   │           └───src
│   │   │               └───main
│   │   │                   └───java
│   │   ├───example_apple_metal
│   │   │   ├───example_apple_metal.xcodeproj
│   │   │   ├───iOS
│   │   │   └───macOS
│   │   ├───example_apple_opengl2
│   │   │   └───example_apple_opengl2.xcodeproj
│   │   ├───example_emscripten_wgpu
│   │   │   └───web
│   │   ├───example_glfw_metal
│   │   ├───example_glfw_opengl2
│   │   ├───example_glfw_opengl3
│   │   ├───example_glfw_vulkan
│   │   ├───example_glut_opengl2
│   │   ├───example_null
│   │   ├───example_sdl2_directx11
│   │   ├───example_sdl2_metal
│   │   ├───example_sdl2_opengl2
│   │   ├───example_sdl2_opengl3
│   │   ├───example_sdl2_sdlrenderer
│   │   ├───example_sdl2_vulkan
│   │   ├───example_sdl3_opengl3
│   │   ├───example_win32_directx10
│   │   ├───example_win32_directx11
│   │   ├───example_win32_directx12
│   │   ├───example_win32_directx9
│   │   └───libs
│   │       ├───emscripten
│   │       ├───glfw
│   │       │   ├───include
│   │       │   │   └───GLFW
│   │       │   ├───lib-vc2010-32
│   │       │   └───lib-vc2010-64
│   │       └───usynergy
│   └───misc
│       ├───cpp
│       ├───debuggers
│       ├───fonts
│       ├───freetype
│       └───single_file
└───lib
```

I also tried compiling manually using the following command line command : `g++ -std=c++20 -o Project main.cpp glad/glad.c -Iglad -IGLFW -Iimgui imgui/*.cpp -Llib -lglfw3 -lopengl32`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34367424/11107541

Comment: Look at your include directory `set(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/GLFW")`, it contains the directory `GLFW`. Now look at your `#include` path `<GLFW/glfw3.h>` it **also** contains the directory `GLFW`. You can't mention the same directory twice. Change `set(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/GLFW")` to `set(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")`

Comment: Thank you it worked, now it makes sense I misunderstood the function